# How to use the same HTML render different content via different urls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have an HTML page and multiple URLs as follows

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('index', ($scope,$http) => {
  $http.get('/get_js').then((res) => {
    $scope.cat = res.data;
  }, () => {
    alert('database error');
  });
});
```

- `/get_js`
- `/get_node`
- `/get_ng`
- ......

I expect if I query different url, such as `$http.get('/get_js')` or `$http.get('/get_node')` or `$http.get('/get_ng')` it will render different content on the same HTML.

For example, I have several links. If I click on 'a'link, HTML will render some content via '/get_js'. If I click on 'b'link, HTML will render some content via '/get_ng' and so on. Each time, I will click one link.

Could anyone tell me how can I do that?

Thank you very much!

PS: I am using an express server to host the content.

Comment: "_I expect if I query different url_", means you query multiple `urls` in same controller at a time?

Comment: @Sravan   nope, for instance, I have several links, when I click 'a' link, it will render some content via '/get_js'  and so on.

Comment: so you will click one link at a time right?

Comment: @Sravan yes, i will click one link at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can take a `function` and make appropriate `api` call in that function when a `link is clicked` by sending the parameter.

**Steps:**

> 1. Write a funciton which calls each api dynamically depending on the
>      parameter.
> 2. Send the `api` url as a parameter from the respective anchot tag to
>      that function.
> 3. Make the api call in that function and show the response in html

Here is how the function may look, I commented your `API` call.

```
 $scope.linkClicked = function(link)
       {
    //   $http.get('/get_js').then((res) => {
    //     $scope.data = res.data;
    //     }, () => {
    //      alert('database error');
    //    });
        $scope.data = link + ' clicked';
       }
```

**Code:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('index', function($scope) {
   $scope.linkClicked = function(link)
   {
//   $http.get('/get_js').then((res) => {
//     $scope.data = res.data;
//     }, () => {
//      alert('database error');
//    });
    $scope.data = link + ' clicked';
   }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="index">

<a ng-click="linkClicked('get_js')"> Link1 </a>
<a ng-click="linkClicked('get_node')"> Link2 </a>
<a ng-click="linkClicked('get_ng')"> Link3 </a>

<p ng-if="data"> {{data}} </p>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/MpWhmaPybEVb2409xmez?p=preview)